# Angular 1.5 access Controller of Parent in transclude-Block

Tags: angularjs

I've tried to accomplish the following behavior in Angular 1.5:

Assume there are three components:

- Main
- Single
- percent bar

So in the Main-Component, I call single-Component in the template and bind properties to it.

Template of Main:

```
<single myobject="$ctrl.resultset"></single>
```

The single-Component has the transclude-property, so the updated markup looks like this.

```
<single myobject="$ctrl.resultset">
  <percentbar></percentbar>
</single>
```

My question is how can I access the Controller of single-Component in percent bar. I would like to do this:

```
<single myobject="$ctrl.resultset">
  <percentbar asd="$ctrl.myobject"></percentbar>
</single>
```

But this won't work... I hoped that $ctrl referenced to the parent Controller in a transclude-block

I've read the Docs ("Example of a component tree", "Intercomponent Communication") but both of these methods (

*Method 1: Binding, call the child component in Template of Parent-Component and bind properties.*

*Method 2: Intercomponent, works with transcluding and bind the parent-Controller.*

) bounds the components.

Is there a way of loose coupling these components?

Comment: Recently I had a similar problem and the only way I managed is to add 'require' to the child component:  require: {
            selfChosenNameOfController: '^nameOfParentComponent'
        }

Comment: But this i try to avoid, for the case that i want to use the childcomponent may without its "required" parent

Comment: I understand. Maybe not such a great workaround, but you can create a new component that has a template:  '<percentbar></percentbar>' and requires the parent. I don't know exactly what logic you would like to add, but maybe this leads you to an idea. Sorry that I can't help you more:(

Comment: @mr.void you can then require it optionally: `require: { localNamespace: '^^?nameOfParentComponent' }`